# Create a table in Oracle with a default value for a column

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error, ddl, create-table

When I run this query:

```
Create table ACCT_MSTR 
("Acct_no" varchar2 (10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 "SF_no" varchar2 (10),
 "LF_no" varchar2 (10),
 "Branch_no" varchar2 (10),
 "Intro_Cust_no" varchar2 (10),
 "Intro_Acct_no" varchar2 (10),
 "Intro_sign" varchar2 (1),
 "Type" Varchar2 (2),
 "Opr_mode" varchar2 (2),
 "Cust_accut_type" varchar2 (4),
 "Title" varchar2 (30),
 "Corp_Cust_no" varchar2 (10),
 "Aplndt" Date,
 "Opendt" Date,
 "Veri_Emp_no" VARCHAR2 (10),
 "Veri_sign" varchar2 (1),
 "Manager_sign" varchar2 (1),
 "Curbal" NUMBER(8,2),
 "Status" varchar2 (1) DEFAULT (A),
CONSTRAINT Am_Bn_fk FOREIGN KEY("Branch_no") references BRANCH_MSTR ("Branch_no"),
CONSTRAINT  Am_Icn_fk FOREIGN KEY("Intro_Cust_no") references CUST_MSTR ("Cust_no"),
CONSTRAINT  Am_Ian_fk FOREIGN KEY("Intro_Acct_no") references ACCT_MSTR ("Acct_no"),
CONSTRAINT Am_ccn_fk FOREIGN KEY("Corp_Cust_no") references CUST_MSTR ("Cust_no"),
CONSTRAINT  Am_ven_fk FOREIGN KEY("Veri_Emp_no") references EMP_MSTR ("Emp_no") 
);
```

I get this error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
>     00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"

Comment: What does it mean "Status"          VARCHAR2(1)  DEFAULT (A) ? May be 'A'?

Answer (score 5):

String constants need to be enclosed in **single** quotes. Anything *without* quotes is an identifier.

So the `A` in

```
"Status" varchar2 (1) DEFAULT (A),
```

references a column named 'A'.

You want

```
"Status" varchar2 (1) DEFAULT ('A'),
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the default value of the `"Status"` column. String constants in SQL are denoted by single quotes (`'`). Without them, bare words are interpreted as object names, which aren't allowed in this context.

To make a long story short, add quotes to the default value, and you should be OK:

```
"Status" varchar2 (1) DEFAULT ('A'),
-- Here -----------------------^-^
```